# Wordpress returns incorrect image URL for downsized images

Tags: wordpress

I'm experiencing an error regarding in relation to wp_get_attachment_image_src, where I'm not receiving the image size I need to.

I'm setting the following sizes in my `functions.php`-file:

```
// Image Sizes
add_image_size('wide', 1344, 378, true);
add_image_size('mobile', 480, 360, true);
```

However, the frontend isn't giving me the correct URL for `mobile` or `array('480','360')`:

```
print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src($id));
> Array ( [0] => http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/stockmann-150x150.jpg [1] => 150 [2] => 150 [3] => 1 )

print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'mobile'));
> Array ( [0] => http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/stockmann.jpg [1] => 480 [2] => 290 [3] => )

print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, array('480','360')));
> Array ( [0] => http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/stockmann.jpg [1] => 480 [2] => 290 [3] => )

print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'wide'));
> Array ( [0] => http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/stockmann-1344x378.jpg [1] => 1344 [2] => 378 [3] => 1 )
```

I've set `$content_width = 1344;` in `functions.php` before I declare my image sizes.

Also, I checked to see that the image exists which it does:

[image]

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had WPML translations installed and therefore needed to regenerate thumbnails for all the different languages, not only for english.